# i have use two dropdown components in single page but only first of them is showing data not second one in nativescript ios

Tags: ios, nativescript

i have used dropdown components in nativescript ios but only one component is loading the data not second one

```
//this is my code where i have used dropdown

<StackLayout orientation="horizontal" width="100%" class="padding">
      <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="left" width="50%">
        <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, *" columns="auto, *" class="newstack">
          <TextField [(ngModel)]="userRegister.langauge" class="noline"></TextField>
          <DropDown #Langauge hint="Langauge" class="Nopadding" backgroundcolor="transparent" [items]=ArrayLangauge [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex"
            (selectedIndexChange)="onchangeLanguage(Langauge.selectedIndex)" row="0" colSpan="1"></DropDown>
        </GridLayout>
      </StackLayout>


      <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" textWrap="true" horizontalAlignment="right" width="50%">
        <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, *" columns="auto, *" class="newstack" horizontalAlignment="center">
          <TextField [(ngModel)]="userRegister.state" class="noline"></TextField>
          <DropDown #State hint="State" class="Nopadding" backgroundcolor="transparent" [items]="ArrayState" [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex"
            (selectedIndexChange)="onchangeState(State.selectedIndex)" row="0" colSpan="1"></DropDown>
        </GridLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, you have syntax mistake when passing the items in your first drop down control (missing quotes). 
this `[items]=ArrayLangauge` should become

```
[items]="ArrayLangauge"
```

[Here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/stackoverflow/doubleDropDown) you can find basic project demonstrating usage of two drop-downs at one page

Comment: sorry for that missing quotes but my first dropdown loading values perfectly but my second dropdown loading values  null ..and its is showing selected index should be between 0, items.length-1

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing that can be causing problem with your second dropdown is that you are using the same variable name for both the dropdown that is [selectedIndex]="**selectedIndex**" change the name of the string that I have bolded.Try this, apart from that your code is good, I have myself used 5 drop downs in a single page, works for me.

Comment: even i set all selectedIndex name values different different but it shows selectedIndex value should be beetween 0 to item.length-1 and only first dropdown values are visible and remaining are null  and my code is working fine with android but creating problem with ios

Comment: Sorry, till now I have my code running for android only so I can not say for the ios.

Comment: thanks you for your answer but i needed for ios..android working fine